# Does 「兄/姉をやめたい」 sound natural?

Tags: spoken-language

Related to a manga which is named お兄ちゃんはおしまい!

Imagine a transgender girl who has a young brother says 兄をやめたい (I don’t want be your brother anymore), is this wired to be heard by a native speaker?

Comment: The sentence probably works but it would almost certainly mean something very hurtful and mean that you are clearly not intending it to mean

Comment: Just to be sure, no one in that manga has wanted to stop being someone's brother, right?

Comment: @naruto https://youtu.be/hoBBr1xHECs

Comment: Yes but Mahiro never wanted to be a girl. He was accidentally turned into a girl due to his little sister's experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by *weird* and *natural*. 兄をやめたい by itself is a perfectly correct and natural sentence as far as grammar is concerned, but it's definitely a surprising sentence that never occurs naturally in everyday conversation. If you think "I don't want be your brother anymore" is "natural", then 兄をやめたい should be equally natural.

This of course sounds like a serious breakup notice if interpreted in isolation. If the speaker wants to remain the listener's sibling, it has to be accompanied by a sentence like これからはお姉ちゃんになりたい (I wanna be your sister from now).